# Azure Web Publish

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to get to grips with the azure framework and having a moderate amount of success however I have stumbled across a slight issue relating to my login account.

I have an email address that I use in Office 365 and also separately as a personal login to Microsoft services (including azure). Now in hindsight this was probably not the route to go down however it was not always consistent that I could use the office 365 login route in other MS services!

This leads to my issue! Until recently, maybe in the last week, the two accounts were very separate however now when I use my email address to login I am presented with a choice of personal or organisational. I made the mistake when first presented with this dialogue of choosing the organisational option (which links back to the Office 365 account). Unfortunately the Web Publish dialogue in Visual Studio has remembered this and I now can't login to my Azure profile to publish my site!!

Even if I change the account and select the Personal account option I am redirected to go-daddy (who provide my office 365 account) to login which is essentially the wrong account!

Now if you do this in the web browser the choice is stored in a cookie, and a simple clearing of the cache removes the problem however I can't seem to affect the cache of the Visual Studio azure web publish login mechanism!

My question therefore is, how on earth do I clear the cache used in the Azure Web Publish dialogue??

Sorry for the verboseness of my question, I wanted to be as detailed as possible...

Thanks for any help you can offer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can log in to the Azure portal in your web browser, you can download the "publish profile" for your website. Select your website, go to the Dashboard and it's in the "quick glance" section on the right.

[image: Downloading the publish profile]

Clicking the link downloads a .PublishSettings file. If you right-click your project in Visual Studio and select "Publish", you can import this profile from there.

Comment: Excellent, I will try this shortly! I did notice the option to import publish settings but wasn't sure where to get them from!